# How to use multiple UserDetails implementations for login: Spring Security and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am working on a spring boot application and has the following scenario-

1. I have three types of user accounts-  a. Normal Users, b. Admin users c. Company
2. Admin users can create a company entity.
3. Admin users and company need to have login functionality and normal users can access endpoints without login (public pages).
4. Now, the problem is that I have two separate tables for **User (with admin and normal role)** and **Company**. Both implement **UserDetails** and I want to use login functionality for these **different entities.**
5. A user will be able to login with username and password. A company can login with company name (not email) and password.
6. I cannot merge the user and company table because they have different attributes and also, an admin user can create a company.
   So, how can I configure Spring Security for different implementations of **UserDetails** and how to choose at runtime which entity is trying to login whether it is a user or a company? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a details service composed from other services (for company and user).

For company:

```
public class CompanyDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final CompanyRepo companyRepo;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<Company> company = this.companyRepo.findByName(username);
    //handle result
  }
}
```

For user:

```
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepo userRepo;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> user = this.userRepo.findByUserName(username);
    //handle result
  }
}
```

Composed service to use for the actual login:

```
public class CompositeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final List<UserDetailsService> services;

  public CompositeDetailsService(List<UserDetailsService> services) {
    this.services = services;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    for (UserDetailsService delegate : this.services) {
      try {
        return delegate.loadUserByUsername(username);
      } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ignore) {
      }
    }
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("");
  }
}
```

Then autowire the composite service where needed.